# How can I reuse my query method to insert and fetch data from the database in PHP?

Tags: pdo, mysql-error-1064

I made a query method for my class and it works in getting data from DB but it **doesn't work when I start to insert something**.

My query method is this.

```
function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $query = $this->_conn->prepare($sql);
        if(count($params)) {
            $position = 1;
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $query->bindValue($position, $param);
                $position++;
            }
        }

        if($query->execute()) { //error is here based on the error message: SQLSTATE[42000]
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else {
            return false;
        }


        return $result;
    }
```

And when I call the query above, it had an error.

```
function insert($table, $data) {
        if(count($data)) {
            $keys = array_keys($data);
            $values = "";

            $counter =1;
            foreach($data as $field) {
                $values .= "?";
                if($counter < count($field)) {
                    $values .= ", ";
                }
                $counter++;
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`". implode('`, `',$keys) ."`) VALUES {$values}";
            if($this->query($sql, $data)) { //calling the method above
                return true;
            } 
        }

        return false;
    }
```

> I think the error is in the query method and it only works fetching
>   data. How can I make it flexible(like both working on fetching and
>   insert etc. data)?

Comment: UPDATE/INSERT statements do not return a result set, just a status i.e. TRUE (it worked) FALSE (it didnt work)

Comment: PS: In future, please show us the COMPLETE error message

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '???' at line 1' in C:\wamp64\www\security\db.php on line 30
**the error is in the query() method in the $query->execute() part

Comment: Looks like you are missing the commas between your parameter placeholders

Comment: If you dont set `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` then errors dont get picked up until you execute the query, because the query does not actually get sent to the database for compilation until you run the `->execute()`

Answer (score 0):

First about your function. It is excessive and limited at the same time. What you really need is

```
function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $query = $this->_conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);
    return $query;
}
```

So you'll be able to get your existing functionality by simply calling it like

```
$db->query($sql)->fetchAll();
```

but it will be possible to call it with any other kind of query including delete and insert, not to mention using named placeholders as well as positional ones and using other chained methods like fetch() or rowCount()

Now to your error message. *Obviously* it has nothing to do with your function, but with a QUERY you run. When asking How to reuse a query method to insert query, **you have to provide a genuine insert query**, not some gibberish PHP code with erroneous result. It is very important to make sure that your deeds are related to your words. Wanna test an insert query? Work with a query, not PHP code!

Finally, to insert helper. Apart from obvious problems with syntax, it is essentially [prone to SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example), so you have to at lease escape your identifiers or better yet whitelist them.